# Do I have IIS URL_Rewrite module 2.1 installed or is it just 2.0?

Tags: iis

I was told to install URL Rewrite module 2.1 onto my IIS.
I found that I already had URL Rewrite module installed but I am not sure if it is version 2.1 or 2.0 (see below image).

Can someone be kind enough to point it out to me please?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to download the [URL Rewrite 2.1](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and install it.

When I check it under `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features` it shows same version as yours.

[image]

Only difference I notice is the size of the installation.

As the version is same, it looks like you are having the latest version of the URL Rewrite module.

In doubt, you could download it from the link I share here and install it.